# String arrays in files different than arrays.xml

Tags: android, xml, arrays, string

I've googled a lot without finding the solution to my problem.

I'm developing a simple card game with 15 cards. Every card has a 3 meanings.

I've created 15 xml files with a string containing the card name and an array of strings containing the 3 meanings of the card.

I've put all files (ex. card_00.xml, card_01.xml, ...) into the "values" folder, but when I try to access using "R.card_00.meanings"  I'm not able to find my files and my arrays.

Why? Suggestions?

This is an example of card_00.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string-array name="card_00_meanings">
         <item>Red</item>
         <item>Green</item>
         <item>Blue</item>
     </string-array>
</resources>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the content of at least one of those .xml files.

Comment: your arrays id are always R.array.<name> no matter the file they are in. The filename is a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your acces is not correct `R.card_00.meanings`

Look at [String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

- FILE LOCATION:

  - res/values/filename.xml
  - The filename is arbitrary. The  element's name will be used as the resource ID.
- COMPILED RESOURCE DATATYPE:

  - Resource pointer to an array of Strings.
- RESOURCE REFERENCE:

  - In Java: R.array.string_array_name

You should acces by the name assigned to every array and starting with `R.array.`
In your example `R.array.card_00_meanings`

Comment: Thanks to all. it worked for me with R.array.card_00_meanings.